# Pure Component renders when no change is there?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I have a pure Component like this?

```
interface Props {
 checkBoxTitleStyle?: any
  checkBoxBackgroundColor?: any
  onPressCheckBox?: (id, isChecked, selectedArray , options?: CheckBoxOptions) => void
  itemKey?: any
  mainContainerStyle?: any
}

class CheckBoxComponent extends PureComponent<Props> {
constructor()
render()
}
```

Now when i use this pureComponents in my otherComponent

```
   <CheckBoxComponent
          checkBoxKey={checkBoxKey}
          itemKey={get(item , 'id')}
          itemTitle={get(item , 'label', '')}
          isCheckBoxSelected={get(item , 'isChecked' , '')}
          checkBoxBackgroundColor={colors.DuckBlue}
        />
```

If i don't pass the prop mainContainerStyle then it works fine, it renders only when there is some change.

But if i pass mainContainerStyle in props then it renders everytime even if no change. Each render makes the performance slower . Is there is any way to fix it or why it is occuring so.

Comment: How are you passing the mainContainerStyle ? i dont see it in the code

Comment: i have added a new question . 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218097/pure-component-works-like-normal-component-when-i-pass-object-as-a-prop

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't pass to prop literal object like `mainContainerStyle={{...other stuff...}}` and save state of it instead.

**Example**

```js
const { PureComponent, useState, useEffect } = React;

class CheckBoxComponent extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props)}</div>
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [mainContainerStyle, setStyle] = useState({position: 'absolute'});
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const checkBoxKey = 1;
  const item = {
    id: 1,
    label: 'label',
    isChecked: true,
    options: {}
  }
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(options);
  const [itemState, setItemState] = useState(item);
  const colors = {
    DuckBlue: ''
  }
  const get = (item, prop) => {
    return item[prop]
  }
  

return <div>
    <CheckBoxComponent
       checkBoxKey={checkBoxKey}
        itemKey={get(item , 'id')}
        itemTitle={get(item , 'label', '')}
        isCheckBoxSelected={get(item , 'isChecked' , '')}
        checkBoxBackgroundColor={colors.DuckBlue}
        //mainContainerStyle={{}} // causes re-render
        mainContainerStyle={mainContainerStyle} // state
        //options={get(item , 'options')} // causes re-render
        //options={itemState.options} // or
        options={options}
    />
    <button onClick={() => setCount(count => count + 1)}>Change Style</button>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i can do for main container style prop like this . But there is also one prop options in my purecomponent.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218097/pure-component-works-like-normal-component-when-i-pass-object-as-a-prop

Comment: Updated answer. The same story. You have to use `useState` for `options` property

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use state for this. What causes the re-render issue is an inline creation of an object, which you have correctly identified. But the solution is not to add it to state. State is for values that change over time. This value does not. Instead, create a `const` for the objects *outside* of the `App` function. This will not create a new object every render and therefore will not trigger a re-render, but will also not create an unnecessary state value.